# Regular Polyhedrons

Tags: euclidean-geometry, polyhedra, polytopes

In $\mathbb{R}^3$, there are five regular polyhedrons (up to similarity), and can be parametrized by number of vertices, edges and faces. What is the number of regular polyhedrons in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and their parametrization? Please suggest the reference(s) also. (Thanks in advance.)

Comment: There is a pretty decent article [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_polytope) which gives the basic facts and pointers to references.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In short, what happens is the following.  The $n$-dimensional analogue of a Platonic solid is called a regular polytope.  In any dimension you are guaranteed three "boring" regular polytopes: the $n$-dimensional version of the tetrahedron (the $n$-simplex), the $n$-dimensional hypercube, and its dual, the $n$-dimensional version of the octahedron.  In three dimensions, as you know, there are two others.  In four dimensions there are others as well, called the [24-cell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-cell), [120-cell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/120-cell) and [600-cell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/600-cell).  In dimensions five and above the boring regular polytopes are the only ones that exist.

The wiki pages http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_polytopes and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_regular_4-polytope are good places to start.  Coxeter's book *Regular Polytopes* is very comprehensive.  Another approach is to look at these things through their reflection symmetry groups: Coxeter's book is a good source for this too, see also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coxeter_group

Answer (score 1):

Just a comment, but "comments" don't support gif's: The [Tesseract](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesseract)

$\hskip2.1in$[image]

Comment: ... don't get hypnotized!